# one Private Key with two different ERC20 tokens

Tags: tokens, wallets, erc-20

I have an ETH key in my wallet. It has BAT and ELF tokens in it. That's why I can not send or trade this one key with two different tokens (in this wallet).

How can I turn this one key into two keys? A key for BAT and a key for ELF.

Many thanks for your help
(wenn jemand Hilfe auf deutsch anbieten kann um so besser)

Comment: You want to be able to trade the private key of the wallet containing the tokens? Why not just transfer the tokens?

Comment: Hi, Does not go out of the wallet (jaxx). Both tokens are deposited in a key.

Comment: jaxx makes error messages.

Comment: Try this: https://shapeshift.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000884030-I-Sent-My-ETH-Token-to-My-ETH-Wallet-on-Jaxx-or-Visa-Versa-Need-to-Extract

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, you have a ETH wallet, and in it some BAT and ELF tokens. What you want is separate those two in two different wallets with unique keys.
Most simple solution to this is to create a new ETH wallet, and send one of those tokens to that new wallet. keep in mind this will cost GAS so you need to have enough ETH to pay for processing of transaction.

Comment: In this case you can not send anything from Jaxx. There is error message.

Comment: i think you should use MEW or something similar for this operation. not sure how well Jaxx supports tokens.